# Parallelization of nested for loop

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

My original code was -

```py
        for j in tqdm(range(height), position = 0, leave = True):
            y = y0  + j * ystep

            for i in range(width):
                x = x0 + i * xstep
                #Do expensive task
```

To parallelize this I did this -

```py
        ht_iterator = range(height)
        wt_iterator = range(width)
        paramlist = list(itertools.product(ht_iterator, wt_iterator))
        with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
             executor.submit(self.process_single_pixel, paramlist)
```

Where `self.process_single_pixel` is basically the above for loop in the form of a function like so -

```py
    def process_single_pixel(params):
        ht = params[0]; wt = params[1]
        y = y0 + ht * ystep
        x = x0 + wt * xstep
        #do expensive task 
        #expensive task calls a recursive function to implement ray-tracing
```

In short I was earlier iterating over the entire height and width, instead I created an iterator with all possible combinations, so that it can be individually parallelized.

1. **Question :** the program doesn’t complete execution and it seems like it gets stuck in an infinite loop. What am I doing wrong? I
   notice that the program never enters the function which needs to be
   executed and the computer hangs and becomes very slow. Also, what is
   the behavior for functions which do not explicitly return anything?
2. I tried parallelization a dummy function -

```py
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
          ret = executor.map(self.dummy, paramlist)

          for result in ret:
              print(result)

    def dummy(self, params):
        return (params[0], params[1])
```

This gave an error `BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.` which is apparently because these processes need to be guarded by `__main__`?

Comment: Hmm, am I missing the question?

Comment: Was there any speedup?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the question itself. No there was no speed up. instead my computer was lagging and CPU usage was 100% (expected, i guess?) but the output was taking way longer than it should have ( i had to force exit)

Comment: @PyWalker2797--you should add this comment with a question to the original post.

Comment: what is the expensive task like? Because the computation shown could be easily done with numpy in a fast way without multithreading.

Comment: What happens if you call a dummy method (make sure it's still an instance method of your class) that doesn't do much work at all? Is it fast, then, or still slow?

Comment: I tried, it did not work. It gave an error `BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.` which is apparently because the function is not 'guarded'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure it's an answer to the question - but it might help.

This piece of code works fine, and it's basically a template for what you're looking for. Could you please try to run it, and see if it causes any issues?

```
import concurrent.futures
import itertools
import random
import time

class ConProc:

    def dummy(self, param):
        time.sleep(random.random() * 3) # simulate a longer job
        return param[0] * param[1]

    def main(self):
        ht_iterator = range(4)
        wt_iterator = range(5)
        paramlist = list(itertools.product(ht_iterator, wt_iterator))

        with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
            ret = executor.map(self.dummy, paramlist)

            for result in ret:
                print(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cp = ConProc()
    cp.main()
```

Comment: `BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.` this was the error I got when I tried executing your code. Do you know why this might be happening?

Comment: I added 'if __name__ == main'. It worked fine for me without it - but can you try again on your side?

Comment: Also - please note that you can't run it as part of an interactive console. Must be part of a py file executed with python3 my_file.py.

Comment: Okay, the script runs. But how would I do this in the case of my function? Would I have to include an `if __name__ == '__main__' ` guard in my main routine? Because the place where I am attempting to parallelize is inside a function, inside a class.

Comment: Not sure I see the problem. In my example, the parallelized code is also part of a call. The 'if __main__' part is just a top level wrapper for the main function. What's the challenge?

Comment: Oh, okay I got it now.

Comment: Your solution seems like it should work, but I have another problem now -- I have opened a new question for it.